# Textarea border checking for input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Currently my code checks for input in the textareas on the site. If I leave all of them blank, they all get highlighted red when I press the button, which is expected. **But**, when I enter text into 1 or more boxes, it just passes through.

It isn't checking all the boxes everytime I press the button, it validates the submit if 1 box has text in it. What is wrong with the js code?

```
$(window).load( function () {
  $('#form1').on('submit', function(event) {

    // If the form validation returns false, block the form from submitting by 
    // preventing the event's default behaviour from executing.
    if (!validate()) {
      event.preventDefault();
    }    
  });

  function validate() {       
    var success = true;

    // Verify that the user entered some special instructions (we only take special orders!)
    var inputarea = $('.input');

    for(var i = 0; i < inputarea.length; i++)
    {
        if(inputarea.val() === "")
        {
            console.log("Missing textarea input");
            success = false;
            //NEED TO CHANGE THE LINE BELOW SO IT WONT SHOW TEXT, JUST CHANGE BORDER COLOUR
            $('.input').css("border","1px solid red");
        }
    }
    return success;   
  }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/originalwill/5cw1a2c2/

The link won't show my error because it is based on a button request using a form, so it won't work in jsFiddle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in native javascript

```
var inputarea = documen.getElementsByClassName('input');
for(var i = 0; i < inputarea.length; i++)
{
    if(inputarea[i].value === "")
    {
        console.log("Missing textarea input");
        success = false;
        inputarea[i].style.border='1px solid red';
         // or inputarea[i].style = 'border:1px solid red;';
    }
}
```

in Jquery i think this will work

```
$('.input').each(function(i, item) {
      if ($(item).val() === "") {
         console.log("Missing textarea input");
         success = false;
         $(item).attr("style","border:1px solid red;");
         //note it will overwrite your element style in all Input class
      }else{
         $(item).removeAttr('style')
         // to remove border 
     }
   });
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe the following would be a better solution:

```
function validate() {
   var success = true;
   // Verify that the user entered some special instructions (we only take special orders!)
   $('.input').each(function(i, item) {
      if ($(item).val() === "") {
         console.log("Missing textarea input");
         success = false;
         //NEED TO CHANGE THE LINE BELOW SO IT WONT SHOW TEXT, JUST CHANGE BORDER COLOUR
         $(item).css("border","1px solid red");
      }
   });
   return success;   
}
```

In your original code, you had the statement:

```
if (inputarea.val() === "")
```

Notice that this had no relationship to your indexing through the array.  It might have worked with something like the following:

```
if ($(inputarea.get(i)).val === "")
```

which would have obtained the element for the i'th entry and then retrieved its value but I believe the [jQuery.each()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/) function is superior for your task.

A sample [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5cw1a2c2/1/) is provided.

Comment: this code doesn't work, just validates it after clicking the button, no boxes are checked

Comment: @originalwill Apologies ... I made a typo in my code.  That will teach me not to fiddle it.  I have added a fiddle for demonstration now and updated the answer.